# Fret spacing for setar

Tags: fretboard, temperament

What is the formula for calculating the frets spacing on the setar?

It's not straightforward as the guitar because the Setar is based on the 17 tone modes of Persian scale: 256/243 27/25 9/8 32/27 243/200 81/64 4/3 25/18 36/25 3/2 128/81 81/50 27/16 16/9 729/400 243/128 2/1

where the ratios are not evenly spaced.

Thanks

Comment: You have answered your own question.  The spacing of the frets is defined by the intervals of your scale, with the height of the action reckoned in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide also an example ? for example, whats is the distance from the bridge for the note D koron ? thanks

Comment: @ScottWallace Has the right idea - but you want to invert each ratio. So theoretically the first fret will be 243/256 * the scale length of the instrument from the bridge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide also an example ? for example, whats is the formula that gives the distance from the bridge for the note D koron for a scale length of 66 cm ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one of those ratios is D koron?

Comment: D koron correspond to this ratio:   27/25  (large limma)

Comment: No, the fret for the note with ratio 27/25 would be (25/27) * 66 cm from the bridge. Alternatively, you can measure from the nut by subtracting the inverted ratio from 1, so that would be (2/27) * 66 cm away from the nut. This can easily be seen by considering that the fret for the note with ratio 2/1 should be 1/2 along the scale length, or 1/2 * 66 = 33 cm from the bridge and 33 cm from the nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing of the frets is defined by the intervals of your scale, with the height of the action reckoned in. But you want to invert each ratio. So theoretically the first fret will be 243/256 * the scale length of the instrument from the bridge.

**Example:**

If the scale length of the instrument is 66 cm, the fret for the note with ratio 27/25 would be (25/27) * 66 = 61.11 cm from the bridge. Alternatively, you can measure from the nut by subtracting the inverted ratio from 1, so that would be (2/27) * 66 = 4.88 cm away from the nut. This can easily be seen by considering that the fret for the note with ratio 2/1 should be 1/2 along the scale length, or 1/2 * 66 = 33 cm from the bridge and 33 cm from the nut.

Note that these are the theoretical/ideal placements. As mentioned in the comments, you have to also consider the width of each fret, the thicknesses of the strings, and the height of the action if you want the best intonation. I believe a popular technique for luthiers is to start with the ideal calculations and mock up the fretboard. Then do some testing and adjusting and arrive at the precise positions for best intonation through experimentation. Then they make careful and detailed notes and templates about those positions to be able to create identical instruments more quickly.

Comment: Indeed because these websites show completely different results 
 Than the one you mentioned https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setar.    https://ebraminio.github.io/extra/setar.html

Comment: If we apply the classical formula used for the guitar with the frequencies ratio of the setar we get close results as the results mentioned in these websites. I wondered the reasons of the significant gap between formula and these results.

Comment: Surely come from the instrument itself luckily the frets can be adjusted.

Comment: @RomainL.I’m confused. Do you already have answers to your question from another source? If so it would make a big difference to tell us that up front and then explain why you’re still wondering what the formula is.

Comment: Yes but contrary to you I'm not an expert and definitely not a professional. And from my side I found that using only math doesn't give all the answer. Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: @RomainL. I’m not an expert, professional, or any kind of luthier at all. I’m just good at math, which as you point out, isn’t good enough to get it to sound right. I hope the right math can at least get you close and then you can adjust from there.